# Como utilizar Python ChatterBot em página HTML?

Tags: html, python, aplicação-web, chatbot

Estou desenvolvendo um Chatbot em python, utilizando a biblioteca ChatterBot.
Gostaria de saber de que forma eu posso "incorporar" esse chatbot em uma página HTML.

- Sou iniciante.
- Utilizo USB Web Server

Segue o código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

from chatterbot import ChatBot

bot = ChatBot('Bot')

nome = input('Digite seu nome: ')

conv = [
    'Oi',
    'Olá',
    'Tudo bem?',
    'Estou bem obrigado'
]

bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)

bot.train(conv)

print('-='*40)

print('Bem Vindo ao Chat!')

print('-='*40)

while True:

    quest = input('Você: ')

    response = bot.get_response(quest)

    if float(response.confidence) > 0.5:

        print('Bot:', response)

    else:

        print('Bot: Não entendi, isso não está na minha base de dados')
```

Comment: Você precisa utilizar algum WebFramework de Python pra utilizar o Python em uma página HTML por exemplo. Os que eu conheço são o [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) e o [TurboGears](http://turbogears.org/).

Comment: Para que possa utilizar uma I.A no HTML, indico a AIML que é uma linguagem já totalmente voltada para essa área.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai precisar estudar um pouco sobre como funcionam as requisições HTTP e os `form`s do HTML pra poder servir uma página que se comunica com seu servidor.

Para o servidor em si, você tem opções como o `flask` e o `Django` para receber e processar as requisições. O Django é bastante poderoso, mas pode ser complicado de usar pra um iniciante e você muito provavelmente não vai precisar de todas as funcionalidades dele. Recomendo portanto o `flask`, que é bem simples e vai te atender.